# Bootstrap Glypicons doesn't show on second hosting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am using newest Bootstrap 3.3.2 and I put some of Glyhicons into website. On testing hosting everything is fine, glyphicons showing right, but when I copied exact page files to another hosting they just doesn't display. Just empty quare. Do you have any ideas why is this?

Test: http://gfp_white_label.lumi-design.sk/
New: http://globalforexpros.com/

Neb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS YOUR PROBLEM**

In your bootstrap-glyphicons.css you are referencing

`glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot`

but in your fonts folder it is

`glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`

This is the same truth with all your fonts.

glyphicons-halflings is not the same as glyphiconshalflings

Comment: I have, just reuploaded the folder 3 times to be sure, but it still shows 404, that is strange... Have a look: http://globalforexpros.com/includes/fonts/

Comment: Thank you very much Rafael. I am just wondering how is it possible, that on one hosting it works and on the other it doesn't.